# Ursina Engine: Black screen flickers when I use `mouse.locked`, what is that?

Tags: python, game-development, panda3d, ursina

I want to make a 1st person game and the whole problem started by making an accessible inventory. Whenever I used `mouse.locked` (no matter if i do `mouse.locked = True` or `mouse.locked = False`) (it basically makes possible to move the cursor around the screen, not to look around), black screen started flickering over the game window. Any ideas how to fix that?

Code:

```py
          from ursina import *
          from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
          if inventory.visible == True:
                player.speed = 0
                player.jump_height = 0
                grid.visible = True
                mouse.locked = False #If I put this here, black screen starts flickering. Pls help...
                testitem.visible = True
```

Comment: Please make sure to provide all the necessary information for the question to be answerable up front. Offering the "full code", etc, upon request is not allowed on this site.

Comment: @cigien Ok, click [here](https://pastebin.com/qBbUS7YS) then...

Comment: No, a link to a pastebin is not acceptable either. Please include the information as formatted text into the body of the question itself.

Comment: @cigien ok, but the problem is in the `mouse.locked` itself and i need to fix that...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late, but...
I had the problem too. For me it solved the problem by closing all other apps (also background). If MS Teams was opened it flickered. Ursina wasn't the reason.